# Django display 404 on missing template

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

I have a website where some pages are edited by hand. When one of those templates is missing, it just means that the page is not present, so I would like to display an Error 404.

Instead I get an exception TemplateDoesNotExist.

> Is there a way to tell Django to display an error 404 whenever it does not find a template?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want this behaviour for all views on your site, you might want to write your own middleware with a [`process_exception`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception) method.

```
from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found

class TemplateDoesNotExistMiddleware(object):
    """ 
    If this is enabled, the middleware will catch
    TemplateDoesNotExist exceptions, and return a 404
    response.
    """

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, TemplateDoesNotExist):
            return page_not_found(request)
```

If you have defined your own [`handler404`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#handler404) you would need to replace `page_not_found` above. I'm not immediately sure how you could convert the string `handler404` into the callable required in the middleware..

To enable your middleware, add it to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in `settings.py`. Be careful of the position where you add it. The standard Django middleware warning applies:

> Again, middleware are run in reverse order during the response phase, which includes process_exception. If an exception middleware returns a response, the middleware classes above that middleware will not be called at all.

Answer (score 9):

put the return of the response in the view (or whereever the template is rendered) in a try-except block:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist

def the_view(request):
    ...
    try:
        return render_to_response(...)
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: Need to import the exception: `from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist`.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I forget where to import the exception from, since couldn't check. Edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, I know I can do this, but it becomes some boilerplate in al views. I hoped there was a global way to do this.

Comment: If you want to avoid boilerplate, define a function `my_render_to_response` which encapsulates the `try..except` block. Then use `my_render_to_response` in your views instead of render_to_response.

Answer (score -1):

Off the top of my head, but if you set DEBUG=False in your settings, won't you get a 404 then on every error (including TemplateNotFound)?

Comment: I think so, but I need this for testing.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. For errors the default Django behaviour is to run the `server_error` view, will render the `500.html` template and return a page with error code 500. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view