# How to make test case fail if a django template has a rendering error that would silently fail in production

Tags: python, django, templates, testing

I'm aware that django test cases are done with DEBUG=False and TEMPLATE_DEBUG=False, and that I can change it to True for a specific function, using

```
from django.test.utils import override_settings

@override_settings(DEBUG=True)
def test_one_function(self):
    # This test should be failing and is not.
    # If I did not test manually I would'nt know !
    pass
```

But maybe there is a better, more generic solution that apply for eveything at once ?

I have an error in my template : I included another template and the link is broken. If I manually check with DEBUG=True I get a TemplateDoesNotExist error. But during my test case the url is rendered without the broken include, it does not throw an error, and the http_status is 200. I already tested the very generic included template somewhere else, so I don't want to add test to see if what is inside was rendered correctly. But I want to see rendering fails, that's what my test are for !

I tried to set TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID to an Exception (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312135/how-to-make-django-template-raise-an-error-if-a-variable-is-missing-in-context)), but it does not seem to be working for a broken include.

Is there a way to make all rendering error raise en exception during tests, without breaking the django's design principle of not running test in debug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [--debug-mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-debug-mode) to set DEBUG=True for all tests. Example:

```
$ ./manage.py test --debug-mode
```

Another solution is to wait for Django 2.1 (it is not released yet). Documentation  promises that lost includes will not be silenced (see the end of [include tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include)  reference).

Comment: for those looking for reference to `include tag fix`: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27175

Answer (score 0):

[Your question is solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926502/django-display-404-on-missing-template)

There is a difference between template missing and object missing, TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID is called when there is object missing in context

Comment: TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID was removed in Django 1.10