# Redirect Django TemplateDoesNotExist to 404

Tags: django

When the template does not exist, a 500 error returns to the user. I want Django to redirect to the 404 page for any view that gets a `TemplateDoesNotExistError`. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Edit: I'm trying to do this for the view that uses `registration/login.html`, which I believe is a built-in view. I would like to redirect to 404 for all views missing templates, not just a specific one like in [Django display 404 on missing template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926502/django-display-404-on-missing-template)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django display 404 on missing template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926502/django-display-404-on-missing-template)

Comment: Partially! Thank you. I need to override the view that uses `registration/login.html`, which I believe is built-in.

Comment: I would advise against returning a 404, the template simply needs to exist. You can use this to recursively go through links and check if all URLs are accessible and render something in the 200-499 range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the `django.contrib.auth.urls` from the `urlpatterns`. They shouldn't be there if I'm not using them.